Function issue using if else and try catch
I need a dataweave function which extract fix string to convert it into ISO Date String format
fun convertToISO(dateString: String): String =
    if (dateString == null) 
        "" 
    else 
        try 
            ((dateString[6 to -3] as Number) as DateTime {unit: "milliseconds"} as String)
        catch (e) 
            "WRONG FORMAT"

but I also get error says , does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?
Invalid input '"', expected ? (line 8, column 13):


8|             "WRONG FORMAT"
               ^
Location:
main (line: 8, column:13)


You seem to be trying to use Java try-catch syntax however DataWeave is a different language and doesn't have that syntax.
As an alternative you could use the try() and orElse() functions from the Runtime module.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import try, orElse from dw::Runtime

fun convertToISO(dateString: String): String =
        try ( () ->
                ((dateString[6 to -3] as Number) as DateTime {unit: "milliseconds"} as String))
        orElse
            "WRONG FORMAT"
---
convertToISO("123")

Output:
"WRONG FORMAT"

